# Antd - Multiple select boxes remove items already selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I have multiple antd select boxes rendered in a list. Options are populated via an array variable. If I have a value chosen in one select box I don't want to render it as an option in other select boxes. Do I just have to store a list for each select box for options or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Hello @Brandi Can you please follow this article and share a 
minimum reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.